# "Unfortunately Google Play Services has stopped" but map works fine

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I followed steps in the developers guide in programming google maps. My API keys are fine. I also installed apks so that i can run the map application to the emulator.

As i run my android emulator, an error "Unfortunately Google Play Services has stopped" pops up. But the thing is the map works fine after you just click OK.

I just copied all the codes from the beginners guide provided so no need to copy my code here. Anyone knows the problem? thanks

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
I think I've found a possible solution: instead of using the Google Play Services apk from my rooted device, I used the apks included in this link: [Google Play Services 4.1](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/01/09/google-play-services-4-1-begins-rollout-with-turn-based-multiplayer-new-google-drive-api-preview-and-more/) and I haven't seen those crashes anymore.

**OLD PROBLEM**
Same thing here... I've seen this in my logs:

```
01-27 09:49:11.164    2068-2075/com.google.android.gms E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
01-27 09:49:12.554    2068-2068/com.google.android.gms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2558)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1338)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission: Neither user 10042 nor current process has com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1575)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1604)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:551)
        at ghj.c(SourceFile:107)
        at ghj.a(SourceFile:121)
        at ghj.a(SourceFile:216)
        at awe.a(SourceFile:218)
        at avz.a(SourceFile:135)
        at avx.b(SourceFile:104)
        at com.google.android.gms.init.InitializeIntentService.<clinit>(SourceFile:48)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        ...
```

However, that permission mentioned in the logs is included in the manifest correctly.

What I did was to extract the Google Play Services apk from a rooted deviced, and installed it in my x86 emulator via adb.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You can find them in my previous comment (in the link that I shared)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didnt solve mine. My emulator is kitkat and it keeps showing the error, but when i try it on real device <kitkat, no error comes in. I haven't tried yet my app on real kitkat device. Do you think the problem is the compatibility with the latest api version?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible anymore to run Google Play Services without those crashes in the emulator; Google requires "certified" devices to run their services, and the emulator it's not. That's why you don't see those crashes in your real device.

Comment: Yeah. Maybe ill just have to try too on real kitkat device. Well, thanks then

Comment: Not sure 4.1 is also a good idea, this version contains bugs worse than this one ...

Comment: How do I deal with such crashes ? I get them for using admob/In-app-purchases and see the crash reports of them on the developer console website... What do they mean? Is there a way to fix them?

Comment: @androiddeveloper You found solution to this? Would really like to know if you found one.

Comment: @akshayrajkore I don't remember. I think we either updated the sdk versions, or we've added a fallback somehow.